# Cassandra Hector : Query last 5 events from event timeline

Tags: cassandra, hector

Hector: hector-core-1.0-5, cassandra-1.1.2

```
I have a user_event CF created through cqlsh as follows:
user_event(
user_name text,
event_id timeuuid,
event_data text,
PRIMARY KEY(user_name, event_id))
```

The query I'm trying to write in Hector is:
Select the last 5 events for a given user before current time.

My code is as follows:

```
    ...    
    {
        Composite start = compositeFrom(TimeUUIDUtils.getUniqueTimeUUIDinMillis(),
        Composite.ComponentEquality.EQUAL);
        Composite end = compositeFrom(TimeUUIDUtils.getUniqueTimeUUIDinMillis(),
Composite.ComponentEquality.GREATER_THAN_EQUAL);

        List<HColumn<Composite, String>> cList= dao.getCompositeQueryIterator(key,  start,  end, stringSerializer);...
     }

        public static Composite compositeFrom(UUID componentName, Composite.ComponentEquality equalityOp) 
        {
          Composite composite = new Composite();
          composite.addComponent(0, componentName, equalityOp);
          return composite;
        }
```

I cannot figure out what operators and values to use for the start and finish composites so that I'll get back the last n events ordered by time.
Also, another question: Is getUniqueTimeUUIDinMillis() the right thing to use for the event_id or should I create a separate timestamp column and slice on it?

Comment: Are you using CQL2 or CQL3 to create your ColumnFamily?

Comment: I'm using CQL3. I can insert the data correctly, just cant figure out how to write the select query to fetch the last 5  events by without fetching all columns.